# How to clear SendKeys after call

Tags: .net, vb.net, sendkeys

This is my code to close a dialog of PhotoShop:

```
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("PhotoShop")

     AppActivate(p.Id)

     Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
     My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("{ESC}")
     Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
     Exit For

Next p
```

When the program finishes, the following dialog is displayed:

```
 MessageBox.Show(Me, "OK", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

I am executing my program on another PC using Remote Desktop.

If I open Remote Desktop and wait for `Process` to complete, the "OK" dialog displays.

I then execute my program and close Remote Desktop before the application finishes.

After my program finishes I re-open Remote Desktop again and the dialog "OK" was closed.

I think event call "ESC" recall when reload Screen.
How clear event `SendKeys`?

Comment: are you sure that your dialog "OK" was closed? It may just appeared behind other windows. Try doing alt+tab to see if it is there

Comment: I am sure, dialog "OK" was closed.

Comment: have you checked if there is any exception? such as [SecurityException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127847(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Dialog "OK" still display ok. But if i open window Remote , Dialog "OK" will close